# polynomials answer the question

Tags: polynomials

If two zeros of the polynomial $x^4-6x^3-26x^2+138x+35$ are $2+\sqrt3$ and $2-\sqrt3$. Find other two zeros

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 here is a link to mathjax. Also include what you have tried when you ask a question on this site.

Comment: Get the monic quadratic with the two given roots. Divide the quartic by this quadratic. Solve the quotient. Answer.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hxgxtzkpuh

Comment: By Vieta's formulas, the sum of the remaining roots is $6 - (2+\sqrt{3})-(2-\sqrt{3})\,$. Their product is $35 / \big( (2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3}) \big)\,$. Then you are looking for two numbers whose sum and product you know.

Answer (score 1):

If two roots are $2-\sqrt 3,2+\sqrt 3$ one factor is 
$$(x-(2-\sqrt 3))(x-(2+\sqrt 3))=(x-2)^2-\sqrt 3^2=\\x^2-4x+4-3=\\x^2-4x+1$$now divide $x^4-6x^3-26x^2+138x+35$ by $x^2-4x+1$